# Creating a pop-up window from custom pushbutton python

Tags: python, pyqt, popupwindow, qpushbutton

I am trying to create a pop-up window that gets popped-up from pressing on a QPushButton. However, I have a separate QPushButton class that I would like to use. I can't seem to get it working. Anything I am doing wrong?

```
#import ... statements
import sys

# from ... import ... statements
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase, QColor, QPalette, QMovie
from skimage import transform, io

# Create main window of the widget
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Set a title inside the widget
        self.titleLabel = QLabel()
        titleText = "some title text"
        self.titleLabel.setText(titleText)

        # Give the label some flair
        self.titleLabel.setFixedWidth(1000)
        self.titleLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(link_to_custom_font)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("custom_font_name")
        font.setPixelSize(50)
        self.titleLabel.setFont(font)


        # Set first button - The "Yes" Button
        self.btn1 = myButtonOne("Yes")

        #Initialize GUI
        self.layoutGUI()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.fromleft = 200
        self.fromtop = 100
        self.w = 1000
        self.h = 500

        self.setGeometry(self.fromleft, self.fromtop, self.w, self.h)

    def layoutGUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.setSpacing(20)

        hbox.addWidget(self.btn1)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.titleLabel)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

class myButtonOne(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myButtonOne, self).__init__(parent)

        # Set maximum border size
        imSize = io.imread(imagePath)
        imHeight = imSize.shape[1]
        imWidth = imSize.shape[0]

        # Set first button - The "Yes" Button
        yesImage = someImagePath
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(" + yesImage + ");"
                           "background-repeat: none;"
                           "background-position: center;"
                                                                 "border: none")
        self.setFixedSize(imWidth, imHeight)

        self.clicked.connect(self.buttonOnePushed)

    def buttonOnePushed(self):
        textView().show()

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        newImage = someOtherImagePath
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url("+newImage+");"
                           "background-repeat: none;"
                           "background-position: center;"
                                                                 "border: none")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        newImage = someImagePath
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url("+newImage+");"
                           "background-repeat: none;"
                           "background-position: center;"
                                                                 "border: none")

class textView(QWidget):
    def __init(self):
        textView.__init__()

        theText = QLabel()
        #define sizes
        self.height = 550
        self.width = 250

        # Open QWidget
        self.initUI()

        # Set the text for the QLabel
        someText = "Some Text for the label"
        theText.setText(someText)


    def initUI(self):
        self.show()

# Start GUI
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So, I am trying to keep the QPushButton classes separate, so that I can customize them. I would like to keep it like that, especially to keep it clean and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off - please read: **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. 
I had a lot of work minimizing your code, which wasted a good amount of *my* time.

Nonetheless, here is **a minimal working code, with your own button class:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget,  QLabel, QVBoxLayout

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.titleLabel = QLabel( "some label text" )
        self.btn1 = myButtonOne( "button text" )

        hbox = QVBoxLayout() # one vertical box seemed enough
        hbox.addWidget( self.titleLabel )
        hbox.addWidget( self.btn1 )
        self.setLayout( hbox )

class myButtonOne(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(myButtonOne, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.buttonOnePushed)
        # add your customizations here

    def buttonOnePushed (self) :
        self.t = textView()
        self.t.show()

class textView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(textView, self).__init__()
        self.theText = QLabel('test', self )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**What have you done wrong in your code?**

using `textView().show()` creates a local version of you textView-class and show()'s it:

```
def buttonOnePushed(self):
    textView().show()
```

But, `show()` means that the code continues, where the end of your code comes, which results in cleaning up the locals. End - it's just shown for a microsecond.

```
def buttonOnePushed (self) :
    self.t = textView()
    self.t.show()
```

The code above stores the var as instance-attribute of the button, which is not cleaned up.

---

Furthermore you misspelled the `init` in your textView-class:
"__init" should be `__init__`  -  else it is not called when using the constructor:

```
class textView(QWidget):
    def __init(self):
        textView.__init__()
```

---

Finally, you wanted to called `show()` twice:

1. in your textView-init you call `initUI()` which is calling `show()`
2. you calling show manually with `textView().show()`

Hope this helps! I did not include your personal style adjustments for readability.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply, this works like a charm!